# different results between map.google.com and google api for javascript

Tags: google-maps

i'm making simple website that helps to find direction between 2 points.
and i found something strange.
if i search through map.google.com it returns exact results, but mine dose not.
for example, i set "New York University, New York, NY, United States" as origin and "260 Broadway New York NY 10007" as destination using map.google.com
[using map.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w75GM.png)

if i use my website using googleMap API->
[using api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbglL.png)

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDs8SYxRh-pMXa9Qe-K1nVY0g3CLpmJ9mo&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

```html
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
    markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    markerArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

  

  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('pac-input').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('pac-input2').value,
    travelMode:  google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  }, function(response, status) {
    // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
    // markers for each step.
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML =
          '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     //showSteps(response, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
  } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The [posted code returns the correct result for me](http://jsfiddle.net/16tf8uzt/).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have places autocomplete inputs and read value of these inputs in your code.

I can suggest using the place ID from places autocomplete in your directions service. This way you will be sure that you work with the address that was chosen.

Look at this example and type there your addresses http://jsbin.com/xuyisem/1/edit?html,output